# Palindrome product output for Project Euler 4

Tags: java

I don't understand why I am not getting palindromes for my output. I have a suspicion it has the problem lies within the inner for loop, but I would appreciate any input.

```
/*
 * 
 * A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
 *
 *  Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
 *
 */

public class projecteuler4 {

public static boolean isPalindrome(String palindromeCandidate) {

    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(palindromeCandidate);

    if (sb1.equals(sb1.reverse())) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String answer;

    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= 999; j++) {
            int ans = i * j;
            answer = Integer.toString(ans);
            if(isPalindrome(answer)) {
                System.out.println(answer);
            }
            else 
                continue;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `StringBuilder`s that contain the same string are not equal, so you need to compare the strings that return from them:

   ```
   return palindromCandidate.equals(new StringBuilder(palindromeCandidate).reverse().toString());
   ```
2. I know it's non of my buissness, but this is a very expensive way to solve this riddle. I suggest you think of a more mathematical solution.

Comment: +1: And start with the largest numbers instead of the smallest. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare strings in your palindromeCandidate method not StringBuilders so further change

```
if (sb1.equals(sb1.reverse())) 
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

to

```
return palindromeCandidate.equals(sb1.reverse().toString());
```

`StringBuilder` methods chain, so the `sb1.reverse()` method returns itself after performing a reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (sb1.equals(sb1.reverse()))
```

with

```
if (sb1.toString().equals(sb1.reverse().toString()))
```

Note: you also don't need the `continue` at the end of the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this...

```
public class LargestPolindrome {
static List<Integer> polindromes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int polindrome = 0;
    for (int i = 999; i > 1; i--) {
        for (int j = 999; j > 1; j--) {
            polindrome = i * j;
            if (isPolindrome(polindrome)) {
                polindromes.add(polindrome);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(polindromes);
    System.out.println(polindromes.get(polindromes.size() - 1));
}

public static boolean isPolindrome(final Integer num) {
    final int rer = Integer.valueOf(new StringBuilder(num.toString()).reverse().toString());
    return rer == num;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. There is a function isPallindrome. It checks a number is palindrome or not. In my main function. I have run a for loop and a inner loop of the problem to get two product less than 1000 as the problem instructed. Then , I have checked , if the result is palindrome it will added to the palindrome arraylist. Finally , I have output the max value from the arraylist.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    long result = 0;
    List<Long> palindrome = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
            result = i*j;
            if(isPallindrome(result)){
                palindrome.add(result);
            }
        }

    }
    long i = Collections.max(palindrome);
    System.out.println(i);
}
public static boolean isPallindrome(long n){
    long pallindrome = n;
    long reverse = 0;
    while(pallindrome!=0){
        long remainder = pallindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        pallindrome = pallindrome / 10;
    }
    if(n == reverse){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```